# Package private modifier in Scala 2.8

Tags: scala, package, private

If I try

```
private[com.company.foo] def bar(xml: XmlPath) = {
```

I get

```
[error]     ... ']' expected but '.' found.
[error]     private[com.
[error]                ^
```

What's with that? I can only make it package-private to com.*, or...?

Comment: Answered by @Nikita, but I like Robin's syntax better ... should propose it to be added as a language feature, makes more sense to me ...

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can only define the enclosing package, within which the code is defined:

```
package com.company.foo

class Bar{
  private[foo] def bar(xml: XmlPath)
}
```

and if you want to set it to company:

```
private[company] def bar(xml: XmlPath)
```