# How do I make a package in Scala private?

Tags: scala, package, access-modifiers

If I have a package hierarchy in Scala like this:

```
package toplevel {
  package a {
    // some interesting stuff
  }

  package b {
    // more interesting stuff
  }

  package utility {
    // stuff that should not be accessible from the outside
    // and is not logically related to the project,
    // basically some helper objects
  }
}
```

how can I forbid the users of package `toplevel` to see or import package `utility`?

I tried with `private[toplevel] package utility { ...` but got this error: `expected start of definition`.

I've searched for this and was overwhelmed by false positives: everything I got was about making things package-private and this is not my question.

Comment: Why do you need that utility package? Wouldn't a private object be more suitable there?

Comment: I need the package to put some meta stuff that simplifies development of the other packages. Such stuff should probably be in a separate library but we don't want the extra dependencies. I'd like it to be a package because it contains 6 objects/classes already with probably more to come. Putting them all in one object would mean that they have to be in the same file and that would become too messy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't: packages don't have access levels.

Or rather, you can, by using [OSGi](https://www.osgi.org/) and not exporting them, but this is a very heavy-weight solution if you don't need it for some other reason as well.

Answer (score -1):

To reach the same goal as private packages in Java you can use augmented access modifiers. Inside your package utility you restrict access with private[utility]. This way the package member is available only inside the package utility itself.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The question is how to make the entire package private, not how to make individual classes package-private.

Answer (score -2):

```
    You can only define the enclosing package, within which the code is defined
```

[Answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9032842/3301316) here.

Comment: The question is how to make the entire package private, not how to make individual classes package-private.