# Testing a private method with access modifier in Scalatest

Tags: scala, unit-testing, scalatest, private-methods

I have the following issue.

Suppose I have the following class (example from here: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21369093/how-can-a-private-class-method-be-tested-in-scala) ):

```
package com.example.people

class Person(val age: Int)

object Person {
  private def transform(p: Person): Person = new Person(p.age + 1)
}
```

So I have a package, and inside it I have a class with a private method.

Now I know using scalatest I can do something like this. In my test folder I have:

```
import org.scalatest.{ FlatSpec, PrivateMethodTester }

class PersonTest extends AnyFunSuite with PrivateMethodTester {

  test("A Person" should "transform correctly") {
      val p1 = new Person(1)
      val transform = PrivateMethod[Person]('transform)
      assert(p2 === p1 invokePrivate transform(p1))
    }
  }
```

Now, my question is, if I add an access modifier to my private method as follows (similar to the answer in this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032631/package-private-modifier-in-scala-2-8)):

```
package com.example.people

class Person(val age: Int)

object Person {
  private[example] def transform(p: Person): Person = new Person(p.age + 1)
}
```

The test complains that transform is no longer a private method.

Is there a way I can still use the private method tester, even if I have an access modifier for a private function?

Comment: Why do you need the private method tester if the method is no longer private? Just call it directly.

Comment: Thanks @Thilo, the reason is my test suite is not in the example package, but as Mario mentioned below, I can just add the test to the package.

Comment: Tests should always be in the same package as the class they are testing. And you shouldn't need to test private methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given

```
package com.example.people

class Person(val age: Int)

object Person {
  private[example] def transform(p: Person): Person = new Person(p.age + 1)
}
```

you just have to make sure that corresponding test is also within `example` package

```
package example

class PersonTest extends AnyFunSuite {
  test("A Person should transform correctly") {
    val p1 = new Person(1)
    Person.transform(p1)    // transform is now accessible
    ...
    }
  }
}
```

in which case there is no need for `PrivateMethodTester` because `private[example]` makes the method available to all the members of `example` package.

Comment: Thanks @Mario, but if I add my tests to package example, wouldn't users of my library be able to access personTest? Is there a way to prevent users from doing so?

Comment: @finite_diffidence Sources under `src/test/scala` should not end up in the packaged/assambled jar. Also note, in general, it is good practice to have tests mirror the package structure of main sources

Comment: Doing so, it is making the def public for all `example` package, in main and test sources.
So the goal of `private` is almost completly lost here.

The question is still open for me: how can we test a private fonction ?

Comment: It's like Java's `package`